# Conocer si una fila de un dataframe tiene un valor NaN - Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy intentando aprender y coger soltura con pandas (cosa que me está costando). Yo tengo un dataframe similar a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo quiero saber si hay algún valor NaN, None o NaT en el conjunto aplico el siguiente código.

```
t = df.isnull().any().any()
print t
```

Si lo quiero saber por columnas aplico este,

```
r = df.isnull().any()
print r
```

Si lo quiero saber valor a valor,

```
a = df.isnull()
print a
```

Pero ¿Y si quiero saber que filas tienen al menos un valor perdido? Es decir, que me muestre que filas tienen NaN, None o NaT.

No consigo nada coherente, todas las pruebas me han llevado a error o a los casos anteriores.

**EDITO**

¿Y si lo que quiero es saber que filas tienen **más de un valor perdido entre sus diferentes columnas**? Por ejemplo, saber que filas (muestras) tienen entre todas sus columnas 2 o más valores perdidos.

Cómo ya ha respondido antes Abulafia, para saber si una fila tiene un valor perdido aplico,

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1)`
```

Se me ocurre que (pero no funciona),

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)>1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indicas en la pregunta, el resultado de:

```
df.isnull()
```

es un dataframe con tantas filas y columnas como `df`, pero cuyos valores son booleanos: `True` en las casillas en que había un NaN o equivalente, y `False` en las demás.

A este dataframe se le puede aplicar el método `.any()` que lo examina por defecto por columnas. El resultado será una Serie (unidimensional) con tantos elementos como columnas tenía `df`, siendo su índice el nombre de cada columna y sus valores un `True` en los elementos que representan a columnas que contienen algún `True`.

Pero lo que no sabías es que a `.any()` se le puede pasar un parámetro para que opere por filas en lugar de columnas:

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1)
```

En este caso el resultado es una Serie (unidimensional) con el mismo *index* que el `df` original y con valores booleanos que son el resultado de aplicar `any()` a cada fila.

Comment: ¡¡¡Genial!!, y corrígeme si me equivoco pero cómo me has enseñado esta mañana, si solo quiero mostrar los resultados positivos haría `print(a[a])` donde `a=df.isnull().any(axis=1)`

Comment: @NEA Efectivamente!

Comment: Disculpa no se si he hecho bien en reformular el post o si debería haber hecho uno nuevo, pero sigo probando diferentes cosas a ver si le pillo el truco a Pandas (perdón por ser tan pesado)

Comment: @NEA Respecto a tu edición, `a = df.isnull().sum()` y luego `a[a>1]`. Pero no me caben las explicaciones, si las necesitas haz una nueva pregunta :-)

Comment: Hice una nueva pregunta :S